# How to trigger mailto in AngularJS controller without changing window location

Tags: angularjs, mailto

I have an angular controller that triggers a "mailto" link when a mail icon is clicked

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('header', {
    template: '<a href="" ng-click="headerCtrl.mailTo()"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
    controller: HeaderController,
    controllerAs: 'headerCtrl'
  });

function HeaderController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.sendMail = sendMail;

  function sendMail(response) {
    var email = 'test@mail.com';
    var subject = 'email%20subject';
    var body = 'email%20body';
    vm.mailToUri = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body;
    $window.location = vm.mailToUri;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is running in the same application as a directive that calls a logout url when the browser is closed

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('onCloseLogout', onCloseLogout);

function onCloseLogout($http, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function () {
      $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $http.get('/logout');
      };
    }
  };
}
```

So, when the email link is clicked, the onCloseLogout directive is triggered, and the user is logged out.

Is there another way to open an email in angular, or to send a get request to the logout URL on browser close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had over engineered the solution. I added the mailToUri to the anchor tag as the ng-href attribute and it all works fine now

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('header', {
    template: '<a ng-href="{{headerCtrl.mailToUri}}"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
    controller: HeaderController,
    controllerAs: 'headerCtrl'
  });

function HeaderController() {
  var vm = this;

  var email = 'test@mail.com';
  var subject = 'email%20subject';
  var body = 'email%20body';
  vm.mailToUri = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body;
}
```